# customized editable text field with predefined width and height

Tags: blackberry, customization, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

[image]

i am developing a mobile app in blackberry 7,i need to create a editable text field as shown in below figure with save and clear button.initially it has to show customized edittext field with predefined width(fixed as it should not exceed the defined layout) and height,and automatically get appended by new line if user requires to enter more characters after reaching predefined space as user keeps filling the field.

i googled, but i did not get any source which is similar to this.please help me by providing any suggestion or with samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry fields decide their size in their `layout` field. I'm not entirely sure what `EditField` does in its layout, but I was able to get the behaviour you want by setting the extent. Every time the edit field text will wrap, `layout` will be triggered so that it can grow.

```
    EditField editField = new EditField()
    {
        private final int MIN_HEIGHT = 200;

        protected void layout(int width, int height)
        {
            super.layout(width, height);
            if (getHeight() < MIN_HEIGHT)
            {
                setExtent(getWidth(), MIN_HEIGHT);
            }
        }
    };
    editField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(1, 1, 1, 1)));
    add(editField);
```

Comment: thankyou for providing this code it works .and now i want clear the characters as user press the clear button how could i implement that function

Comment: What do you mean by clear button, the back, or backspace? If you mean the back button, do you want to clear all characters, or just the last one?

Comment: sir clear button is the bitmapfield placed over my screen(look at screen shot) .if i click on that clear button all the characters whatever user has entered should be cleared in one shot